# How to set up calls from PC to go through my phone

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, voip, call

I want to recieve calls on my PC from my phone on my actual SIM number.

Something like-

Someone calls me on my phone-> My Phone routes the call through Wifi to my PC -> I can talk to the person through my PC

And similarly I want to be able to place calls from my PC. The phone essentially acts as a hub.

Is there any way you could do that?

> P.S.: I know and have tried Windows 10's `Your Phone`, but that requires PC to be connected to the phone through Bluetooth, thereby limiting its range and defeating the purpose. I want my phone to be anywhere in the house, connected to Wifi, and still be able to make calls.

Comment: I would wonder how likely this is to exist. In my experience, Wi-Fi calling is directly available from the phone itself. And connections directly to a computer are typically over USB or Bluetooth, not Wi-Fi.

Comment: I don't you can. You need the SIM card directly on the PC, for example with a SIM reader.

Comment: Bluetooth has built in protocols to deal with hands-free calling and such.  Wifi does not.  Someone *could* write it or figure out a way, nobody has.  `but that requires PC to be connected to the phone through Bluetooth, thereby limiting its range and defeating the purpose` .. makes no sense to me.  You mean that having your phone go outside of 30 feet from the PC defeats the purpose?  Then HOW are you going to answer it on the PC if you aren't BY THE PC?